# Remove all localstorage items with the value true?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'd like to reset localstorage daily and remove a lot of the old storage but also keep a few important items for *some* users (localStorage.clear() not an option).

The keys I'd like removed all have the value **true**. The important items to keep have different values. Rather than listing every single item (200+) that I want to remove do you think it's possible to remove all at once by targeting the value of true?

As you can see from this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xur402n/7/) example the *one* button adds three items to local storage and two of them have the true value.

```js
$(".no").on('click', function() {
  localStorage.removeItem(true)
});

$(".one").on('click', function() {
  localStorage.setItem("one", true)
  localStorage.setItem("two", "yes")
  localStorage.setItem("three", true)
});
```

```css
.no {
  width: 40px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.one {
  width: 40px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">one</div>
<br>
<div class="no">clear</div>
```

Comment: For your use case, you should use indexed db, rather than localStorage. It will help you make queries

Comment: You could iterate the keys from `localStorage.key(0)` to `localStorage.key(localStorage.length - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Get list of item keys from localStorage:

```
const localStorageKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
```

Check where value is true and remove:

```
for (let key of localStorageKeys) {
  if (localStorage[key] === "true") {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the below code.

```
    const localStorageKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
      for (let key of localStorageKeys) {
        /*Also check with True as well if value is added like this  */
       if (localStorage[key] === "true" || localStorage[key] === "True") {
        console.log(key);
       }
     }
```